# Why would a query param be undefined in NextJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm calling a page withRouter(Page) and expect the variable for the page (the page is called [category].js) to be present on initial page load. Query itself is there, the key is there, but the value is 'undefined.' There seem to be a few calls to getInitialProps on the server side with 2/3 being undefined.

The react component has a constructor, etc. it's not a functional component.

This is my current getInitialProps:

```
Category.getInitialProps = async ({ req, query }) => {
  let authUser = req && req.session && req.session.authUser
  let categoryData = {}
  let categoryItemData = {}
  let category = query.category
  if(category){
    let res = await fetch(url1,
    {
        method: 'POST',
        credentials: 'include',
    })
    categoryData = await res.json();
    let categoryItemsRes =  await fetch(url2, 
        {
            method: 'POST',
            credentials: 'include',
        })
    categoryItemData = await categoryItemsRes.json();
  }

  return { query, authUser, categoryData, categoryItemData }
}
```

Comment: Appears getInitialProps is being called twice, not sure why that would be the case. Once with the data, once without.

Answer (score 5):

This might be redundant at this point, but I ran into this as well and found the docs explain this [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/automatic-static-optimization)

> During prerendering, the router's query object will be empty since we do not have query information to provide during this phase. After hydration, Next.js will trigger an update to your application to provide the route parameters in the query object.

You might try this instead:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(ctx) {
  const { id } = ctx.query;
  return {
    props: {
      id,
    },
  };
}
```

This way it gets the query params *when rendering server side*, so they're instantly available.

Comment: ^ great answer. First line on the following link says "If you export an async function called getServerSideProps from a page, Next.js will pre-render this page on each request using the data returned by getServerSideProps." So essentially, NextJS automatically detects that function simply by putting it on the page. https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering

Answer (score 0):

For others who use `express` custom server, to fix the `undefined` params, we have to set the dynamic route at `server.js` as follow:

```js
# server.js
...

app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express();
  ....

  server.get('/product/:category', (req, res) => {
    const { category } = req.params;
    return app.render(req, res, `/product/${category}`, req.query)
  })
  
  ...
}
```

And then, as Valentijn answers, we can get the category params.

```js
# pages/product/[category].js
....

export async function getServerSideProps(ctx) {
  const {category} = ctx.params;
  return {
    props: {
      category
    },
  };
};

...
```

The key is dynamic path `/product/${category}`. Don't use `/product/:category`